# How do I remove carriage returns from the input file using Bash?

Tags: bash

I'm reading a gzipped csv file with Bash. I'm able to get the rowcount using `zgrep` but when I store that rowcount value in a variable, I think the carriage return character is also being stored. So instead of `10`, the variable stores `10\r`.

When I `echo` the variable, it looks like a number, and I can't see the carriage return character.

I'm trying to do some math on the variable by comparing it to another variable that stores an integer, which is why this is throwing an error.

How do I remove the carriage return character?

The [top answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481278/syntax-error-invalid-arithmetic-operator-error-token-is) seems relevant, but I can't figure out what `done` is and how to apply it to my situation

This is the function that returns a file's row count: `campaignFileRowCount=$(zgrep -w "campaign"$today".csv.gz" rowcountfile_"$today".csv.gz | cut -d, -f2)`

Then when I try to do this `echo $((campaignFileRowCount - 0))`, I get the error `")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "`

Comment: `done` is just the keyword that closes the body of the `while` loop.

Comment: Note that the carriage return is only visible in an `echo` if there's something after it: echoing `10\rasdf` will just print `asdf`, since the carriage return resets the line and will start printing `asdf` over `10`.

Comment: Added in details on what I'm doing. Notepad++ also shows the rowcountfile of using Windows formatted EOL conversion

Answer (score 1):

#### Method 1

Replace:

```
campaignFileRowCount=$(zgrep -w "campaign"$today".csv.gz" rowcountfile_"$today".csv.gz | cut -d, -f2)
```

with:

```
campaignFileRowCount=$(zgrep -w "campaign"$today".csv.gz" rowcountfile_"$today".csv.gz | tr -d '\r' | cut -d, -f2)
```

The command `tr -d '\r'` will remove all occurrences of carriage-return from the output.

#### Method 2

Remove trailing carriage returns using the command (bash required):

```
campaignFileRowCount=${campaignFileRowCount%%$'\r'}
```

This is an example of *suffix removal*.  The shell removes from the end of `campaignFileRowCount` anything that matches the pattern shown following the `%%`.