# For loop and confition including Curl command

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script where I enumerate users by checking the HTTP reponse length. I want to get output "good" when response is not equal 23, however I get these errors now:

```
for ((i=113;i<=115;i++)); do
  if [[curl -i -s -k  -X 'GET' "http://myurl/some.asp?q=$i" |
       grep Content-Length | cut -d' ' -f2 != 23]]
  then
       echo "good"
  fi
done
```

Output:

```
bash: [[curl: command not found
cut: !=: No such file or directory
cut: 23]]: No such file or directory
cut: !=: No such file or directory
cut: 23]]: No such file or directory
bash: [[curl: command not found
cut: !=: No such file or directory
cut: 23]]: No such file or directory
bash: [[curl: command not found
```

If I simply make a script without if condition, then it works well:

```
for ((i=113;i<=115;i++)); do
    curl -i -s -k  -X 'GET' "http://myurl/some.asp?q=$i" |
    grep Content-Length
done
```

I checked many examples but can't seem to figure out where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Check your script in http://www.shellcheck.net/, it contains some syntax errors.

Comment: As the error message says, `[[curl` is not a valid command. Try `curl` instead.

Comment: @fedorqui indeed there were not spaces after brackets. Now I have `bash: conditional binary operator expected
bash: syntax error near `-i'`. Btw, that site is great! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After updating your initial error, you may have a syntax like (suggestion: put some effort on format, so that it is more clear what you have and what may be wrong):

```
for ((i=113;i<=115;i++))
do
    if [[ curl -i -s -k  -X 'GET' "http://myurl/some.asp?q=$i" | grep Content-Length | cut -d' ' -f2 != 23 ]]
    then
        echo "good"
    fi
done
```

This is returning you the error:

> bash: conditional binary operator expected bash: syntax error near
>   -i'`

Which is normal, because you are basically saying:

```
if [[ command ]]; then ...
```

Where `command` is a set of multiple piped commands. However, in `[[` you just can add expressions on the form `"$var" -eq 23` or `"$(command)" -ne 23`.

So use `$( )` to execute the command: `if [[ "$(command)" -ne 23 ]]`:

```
if [[ "$(curl -i -s -k  -X 'GET' "http://myurl/some.asp?q=$i" | grep Content-Length | cut -d' ' -f2)" -ne 23 ]]
```

Note I am using `-ne` to perform an integer comparison that means "not equal to".

Finally, notice that `awk` alone can do what `grep` and `cut` do in two steps:

```
... | grep "Content-Length" | cut -d' ' -f2
```

This means: check the line containing "Content-Length" and print its second field. `awk` makes it simple by saying:

```
... | awk '/Content-Length/ {print $2}'
```

And last, but not least, your expression `for ((i=113;i<=115;i++))` can be also written as `for i in {113..115}` using [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion).

Comment: Thanks for this response. So final versions is `for i in {113..115}; do if [[ "$(curl -i -s -k  -X 'GET' "http://myurl/some.asp?q=$i" | grep Content-Length | awk '/Content-Length/ {print $2}')" -ne 23 ]]; then echo "good" ; fi; done` but now I get error `")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "` for each iteration. The only similar error I found is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481278/syntax-error-invalid-arithmetic-operator-error-token-is but not sure how that related to my case case. If I switch back to `!=` instead of `-ne` error disappears, but it's not correct.

Comment: @Thomas well this is probably due to having double quotes within double quotes. Try escaping them --> `if [[ "$(curl -i -s -k -X 'GET' \"http://myurl/some.asp?q=$i\" | grep ...`

Comment: @fedorqui No, the quotes outside `"$(...)"` are independent from the quotes inside.  This is one of the few cases where you can nest quotes.

Comment: Awk can do comparison, too; `if curl ... | awk '/Content-Length/ && $2==23 { exit 0 } END { exit 1 }'; then ...`

Comment: @fedorqui well escaping got rid of the error, but not I am pretty sure curl is not executed correctly. I get instantly response that all are 'good', while it's not the case, and usually response takes longer.

Comment: @tripleee but things like `[[ "$(curl -i -s -k  -X 'GET' "http://www.google.com" | grep Content-Length | cut -d' ' -f2)" -ne 23 ]] && echo "yes"` give me an error `")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "`.

Comment: The problem there is that the HTTP header contains a trailing carriage return.  Awk can obiviosly fix that, too; `sub(/\015/, "");`

Comment: @Thomas this is a bit weird. What if we split this in two steps, to debug: firstly get the content: `var=$(curl -i -s -k  -X 'GET' "http://myurl/some.asp?q=$i" | grep Content-Length | cut -d' ' -f2)`. Print that var with `echo "$var"` to see what exactly is there.

Comment: My Awk on OSX doesn't like `$2` even after the `sub`  but I can get the result I want with `awk '/Content-Length/ { if (0+$2 == 23) exit 0; last } END { exit 1 }'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test a result of the command execution you should put it into $() . So the resulting script should look as follows:

```
for i in {113..115}; do if [[ $(curl -i -s -k  -X 'GET' "http://myurl/some.asp?q=$i" | grep Content-Length | cut -d' ' -f2) != 23 ]]; then echo "good" ; fi; done
```

Also I've changed a way you iterate the values. {a..b} in bash provides a sequence from 'a' to 'b'.

Comment: Well it does not work. I get the same output every single time while I am supposed to get different.

Comment: Can you please give some example output you're getting while executing curl? That should help debugging the issue.